# Retrieving formatted text from MySQL database

Tags: html, database, jsp, tags, formatting

I send text from  with html tags to MySQL database:

```
<p>Hello</p><br>
<h3>Header</h3>
```

But when I retrieve it from my database to my JSP page it looks like:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Header&lt;/h3&gt;
```

How to preserve rich text formatting when outputting?

Comment: They are encoded, decode them

Comment: And how to decode them back?

Comment: Sorry but no knowledge about JSP, but I know PHP so logic is same here, in php we use htmlspecialchars decode

Comment: I use <c:out value="${item.text}" escapeXml="false" /> and it works) Thanks anyway)